# Azure Computer Vision - Make Background Transparent Of Any Image Having A Foreground Object

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am looking for a image processing algorithm for removing the background of any image making the image transparent keeping the fore-ground object only.

Right now I am exploring azure cognitive services but it seems like there is no direct service available.

So if anyone could guide me towards the right direction or a step by step guide like how I can make use of azure computer vision to make the background of any image transparent that would be a really great help.

I am looking for any algorithm or any step by step guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recently added the ability to remove the background from images using Azure Cognitive Service's Computer Vision suite.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/how-to/background-removal